# Xcode iOS Instruments:

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I have a build of my app that only crashes when running instruments. The repro case is 100%, but does not crash when running a release build without instruments nor when running a debug build. As Instruments runs a release build I can;t step through and figure out exactly what is crashing. When the build crashes, it does so silently, with no output that I can find. It *only* crashes with Allocations running in instruments.

I am having difficulty tracking down what is happening, Is there an instruments mode I am not aware of that will trap this error and report the specifics to me?

I have read similar questions on Stackoverflow but those questions have not helped me.

The crash acts like a zombie, but *only* happens when instruments are running, and 'zombie detection enabled' doesn't indicate a zombie.

`````
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 209.19 - Device: iPad Air 2 - Runtime: iOS 9.3 (13E230) - DeviceType: iPad Air 2

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000109f03dc0 swift_retainCount + 0
1   liboainject.dylib               0x000000010335d223 oa_swift_tryRetain + 297
2   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000109f14d69 -[SwiftObject retainWeakReference] + 9
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001098b8b6b weak_read_no_lock + 89
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001098b94c6 objc_loadWeakRetained + 104
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001098b94f2 objc_loadWeak + 15
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000108da975c empty + 35
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000108da96fa -[NSConcreteHashTable dealloc] + 46
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001098b9afe objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 232
9   liboainject.dylib               0x000000010335c6e9 ___swapMethods_block_invoke_4 + 272 ````
`````

Comment: Edit the scheme and change the Instruments build to use the Debug build instead of Release.

Comment: Thanks, it still doesn't hit breakpoints when running in debug (I'm pretty much a neophyte with instruments). Not sure what to try next.

Comment: What optimization does your Release configuration use?

Comment: Also please note that you can log to the console even you can't pause, so you can see how far you're getting. You should be able to get (and give us) a much better idea than you have so far of what your app is doing at the time of the crash.

Comment: Curious about how this happen.  Here is I would do, add as much as log, and see it from Window->Devices->[Your Device], check where is stopped.  And exclude the external libraries one by one to see which one cause the crash.

Comment: @matt It's happening in debug also, and only when instruments are run. I'll be in meetings for a lot of today but will try to update the questions when i can.

Answer (score 1):

It happens the same things to me on Xcode 9 using the iOS 10 simulator, default is iOS 11 simulator but I wanted to test also on iOS 10.

So far so bad, any instrument manipulation is causing my application to crash with almost the same backtrace than the one shown here when using iOS 10 simulator.

I tried many things and at last I thought that there may be some incompatibility of Xcode 9 Instrument with older simulator SDK.

So I switched to the iOS11 simulator which is the default one on Xcode 9 and it solve my Instruments issue.

I'm now able to use instrument for memory investigation on my app.